# How do I pass the 301 to this route definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In `routes.rb`. How do I pass the `:301` / `:moved_permanently` to the following route definition?

```
match '/(*path)', :to => redirect { |params, request| Addressable::URI.escape request.url.sub(request.host, "www.#{request.host}") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`redirect` accepts options. One of them is `:status`:

```
redirect(:status => 301) { |params, request| ... }
```

Comment: Just a note. It also seems this kind of redirect is by default a 301. From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection